# Not able to pass variable from one function to another in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, scope

New to Javascript and HTML. In a nutshell, attempting to update score if user enters correct sum of random math problem. Not able to pass the answer of the problem to my function which checks if what the user entered is correct. I just want the score to increase by one. For some reason the function I am passing the parameter "score" to is not being recognized by it. 
Here is a very quick example of my code. More concerned about the logic instead of the looks right now of the program. I know right now the score will not update correctly but the problem lies in the passing of the "answer" variable. I will easily work through the score increase once the function at least gets called. Thank you very much for your time!

```
    <html>
<title></title>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>

<body onload = "displayProblem()">

<script>

function displayProblem(){
 var answer = (firstNum) + (secondNum);    
 var firstNum = (Math.floor(Math.random()*10) + 1);
 var secondNum = (Math.floor(Math.random()*10) + 1);

 document.getElementById("qstns").innerHTML = firstNum +" + " + secondNum    +" = ";

 }  

function checkAnswer(){
  var userAnswer = document.getElementById("answr").value; 
   if(userAnswer === answer){
    updateScore();
    console.log("score updated");
  }
console.log("did not update score");
```

}

```
function displayNext(){
 document.getElementById("next").style.display = "block";
}

function hideNext(){
 document.getElementById("next").style.display = "none";
 }

function updateScore(){
  var score = 0;
  score++;
  document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = score;

}

function clearAnswer(){
  document.getElementById("answr").value = " ";
}


 </script>

<div id="main">
 <div id="qstns">

  </div>


</div>
<input type="text" id="answr">
Score: <label id="score"> 0 </label>

<button type="Sumbit" id="submit" onclick="displayNext(), checkAnswer    ()">Check</button>
<button type="Submit" id="next" onclick="displayProblem(), hideNext(),    clearAnswer()" style="display:none;">Next</button>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

the prob is that every time you call the function "updateScore"
you reset the value of "score" to zero.

one way could be this: read the current score first than increase...

```
function updateScore(){
  var score = pareseInt(document.getElementById("score").innerHTML);
  score++;
  document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = score;
}
```

or this:  set score to "global" than increase...

```
var score = 0;
function updateScore(){
  score++;
  document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = score;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<html>
      <title></title>
      <head>
      </head>
      <body onload="displayProblem()">
        <script>
            var answer;
            var score=0;
            function displayProblem(){   
                 var firstNum = (Math.floor(Math.random()*10) + 1);
                 var secondNum = (Math.floor(Math.random()*10) + 1);
                 answer = (firstNum) + (secondNum); 
                 document.getElementById("qstns").innerHTML = firstNum +" + " + secondNum    +" = ";
             }  

            function checkAnswer(){
                var userAnswer = document.getElementById("answr").value; 
                if(userAnswer == answer)
                    updateScore();
            }

            function displayNext(){
                document.getElementById("next").style.display = "block";
            }

            function hideNext(){
                document.getElementById("next").style.display = "none";
            }

            function updateScore(){
                score++;
                document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = score;
            }

            function clearAnswer(){
              document.getElementById("answr").value = " ";
            }

        </script>
        <div id="main">
          <div id="qstns"></div>
        </div>
        <input type="text" id="answr">Score: <label id="score"> 0 </label></input>
        <button type="Sumbit" id="submit" onclick="displayNext(), checkAnswer    ()">Check</button>
        <button type="Submit" id="next" onclick="displayProblem(), hideNext(),    clearAnswer()" style="display:none;">Next</button>
      </body>
    </html>
```

You had 2 problems; one that `answer` was a local variable to `displayProblem()` and therefore wasn't accessible by `checkAnswer()`, and two that you were using `===` instead of `==`. `===` evaluates both type and value, `userAnswer` and `answer` are of different types so this was evaluating to `false`.

[JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9cnganxz/)

EDIT: `score` will increment as expected.

Comment: Thank you for a fast and very professional response! I have used this site only a very little and will do so more now due to the great knowledge of the community! Thank you again for your help sir!

Comment: If you choose to, you can accept this answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of my answer. It helps other people identify which answer solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<title></title>
<head>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css'>
</head>
<body onload = 'displayProblem()'>
<script>

//'answer','score' variables should be declared outside function globally
var answer=0;
var score=0;

function displayProblem(){
 //var answer = (firstNum) + (secondNum); The calculation should be after assigning value to 'firstNum', 'secondNum'   
 var firstNum = (Math.floor(Math.random()*10) + 1);
 var secondNum = (Math.floor(Math.random()*10) + 1);
 answer = (firstNum) + (secondNum);
 document.getElementById('qstns').innerHTML = firstNum +' + ' + secondNum    +' = ';
 }  

function checkAnswer(){
  var userAnswer = document.getElementById('answr').value; 
   if(userAnswer == answer){
    updateScore();
    console.log('score updated');
  }
  else
    console.log('did not update score');
}

function displayNext(){
 document.getElementById('next').style.display = 'block';
}

function hideNext(){
 document.getElementById('next').style.display = 'none';
 }

function updateScore(){
  score++;
  document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = score;
}

function clearAnswer(){
  document.getElementById('answr').value = ' ';
}
 </script>

<div id='main'>
 <div id='qstns'>
  </div>
</div>
<input type='text' id='answr'>
Score: <label id='score'> 0 </label>
<button type='Sumbit' id='submit' onclick='displayNext(), checkAnswer();'>Check</button>
<button type='Submit' id='next' onclick='displayProblem(), hideNext(), clearAnswer();' style='display:none;'>Next</button>
</body>
</html>
```